# SQL INNER JOIN Multiple Tables Transactions by grade

Tags: sql, inner-join, database

I have a CUSTOMERS table which contains the field GRADE
I have a TRANSACTIONS table with a FK for CUSTOMERID

I am wanting to return a COUNT of every grade

For Example: Return a COUNT of the total number of transactions for CUSTOMERS in grade 5.

I am a little stumped on this. Any insight would be appreciates

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the count for grade = 5 (or any other single grade) you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN customers c ON t.customerid = c.id
WHERE c.grade = 5;
```

If you want to get the count for all grades individually you can do:

```
SELECT c.grade,COUNT(*)
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN customers c ON t.customerid = c.id
GROUP BY c.grade;
```